# Android: How create Image scale animation on SurfaceView Canvas?

Tags: android, surfaceview, 2d-games

For an android 2D-game, I want to create a image scale animation on surfaceview canvas. Following is my working code, I am not sure about the approach is correct or not.

Please suggest me, if I am wrong.

```
public void drawScaledImage(Canvas canvas, Bitmap bitmap, float scale) {
    width = bitmap.getWidth();
    height = bitmap.getHeight();

    Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) (width * scale), (int) (height * scale), false);

    canvas.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, getX(), getActualY(), paint);

}
```

Following code will be executing on every 16ms (FPS 60) with a new scale value.

Please suggest the correct approach to create a image scale animation in android canvas.

I want to create the animation memory and process optimised way.

Thanks.

Comment: use `Canvas#scale()`

Comment: Thanks. It works for me. I did  `canvas.scale(scale, scale, getX() + width / 2, getActualY() + height / 2);` . it is working fine for me.

Comment: good, nice to hear it is working